# Kolmogorov's three series theorem - a valid reference

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm having some trouble in finding a valid reference/document about the famous Kolmogorov's three series theorem. In particular sometimes the statement is something like:

Let $X_i$ be a sequence of real indipendent random variables, then $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}X_i $ converges almost surely in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\forall A > 0$
$$
\begin{cases}
                \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} P(X_i > A) & \mbox{ converges} \\
                \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(X_i1_{(X_i \leq A)}) & \mbox{ converges} \\
                \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} Var{(X_i1_{X_i \leq A)})} & \mbox{ converges}
            \end{cases}
$$
(see https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Three-series_theorem)

other times is something like:

Let $X_i$ be a sequence of real indipendent random variables, then $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}X_i $ converges almost surely in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if
$$
\begin{cases}
                \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} P(X_i > 1) & \mbox{ converges} \\
                \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(X_i1_{(X_i \leq 1)}) & \mbox{ converges} \\
                \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} Var{(X_i1_{X_i \leq 1)})} & \mbox{ converges}
            \end{cases}
$$
see (http://www.iloveproba.com/uploads/4/3/0/9/4309511/threeseries.pdf)

other times is something like:

Let $X_i$ be a sequence of real indipendent random variables, then $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}X_i $ converges almost surely in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\exists A > 0$
$$
\begin{cases}
                \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} P(X_i > A) & \mbox{ converges} \\
                \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(X_i1_{(X_i \leq A)}) & \mbox{ converges} \\
                \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} Var{(X_i1_{X_i \leq A)})} & \mbox{ converges}
            \end{cases}
$$

Pay attention at the quantifiers, they are completely different and I don't understand how it is possible to formulate the same theorem in all of these ways.. are they equivalent statements?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: They are all correct statements.

Comment: Oh.. ok. I see how the last two are equivalent.. but what about the first one and the second one for example? Why is it the case? Thank you in advance for pointing me the right direction!

Comment: Just look at the proof in Chung's book. You will see why are all true.

Comment: Thank you! I will take an attention look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K L Chung (A course in Probability Theory) proves that if the conditions hold for **some** $A$ then $\sum X_n$ converges almost surely. He also proves that if $\sum X_n$ coverges a. s. then  the three series converge for **every** $A$. From these proofs it follows that all of your statements  are true.